# How to check if string value in one column is partially contained in string value of another column using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I check if string value in one column is partially contained in string value of another column using SQL?

If I had to check if col_1 column of tbl table contains 'Mercury', I would do a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col_1 LIKE '%Mercury%'
```

But if I had to check that for every row, if the full value of col_2 is contained partially in col_1, how would I do that.

Something like:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col_1 LIKE col_2
```

won't work. 
I have a solution which involves `SUBSTR`, `INSTR` and `LENGTH` but that makes my query too slow.
Please post your suggestions.
I want to do this in MySQL.

Comment: Searching for substring matches is bound to be slow. It can't use an index, so it's going to require a table-scan.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col_1 LIKE '%'+col_2+'%'
```

---

EDIT: For MySQL, the equivalent syntax would be:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE col_1 LIKE CONCAT('%',col_2,'%')
```

Comment: That's correct. It works :)
Just adding more clarity. In MySQL, we would use concat() instead of the + signs.